# How to change react-select options styles when select

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-select

I am using react-select latest to create an async select component. I am trying to change the background color and border color of the select, once I select some value. I went through the document and tried using **state.isSelected** to conditionally change the background color. But no help.

[image: When no value is selected]

When the value is selected as below, I would like to change the background color and also the border color. But nothing seems to happen. Help would be appreciated

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Method

Refer to document: react-select [customize styles](https://react-select.com/styles)

You can override the default provided styles in different domains.

In this case, the base **control** would be good enough.

```
const customStyles = stateValue => ({
  control: (provided, state) => ({
    ...provided,
    backgroundColor: stateValue ? "gray" : "white"
  })
});
```

---

#### Demo

[image]

---

#### Source

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Select from "react-select";

const options = [
  { value: "chocolate", label: "Chocolate" },
  { value: "strawberry", label: "Strawberry" },
  { value: "vanilla", label: "Vanilla" }
];

const customStyles = value => ({
  control: (provided, state) => ({
    ...provided,
    alignItems: "baseline",
    backgroundColor: value ? "gray" : "white"
  })
});

const App = () => {
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState("");
  const onChange = e => {
    setSelected(e.value);
  };
  const onClickButton = () => {
    setSelected("");
  };
  const displayItem = selected => {
    const item = options.find(x => x.value === selected);
    return item ? item : { value: "", label: "" };
  };
  return (
    <>
      <Select
        options={options}
        styles={customStyles(selected)}
        onChange={onChange}
        value={displayItem(selected)}
      />
      <button onClick={onClickButton}> Clear Selection </button>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

[image: Edit cocky-worker-h2sgn]

Comment: How do you set styling when the dropdown is open? I see blue borders there which I don't want to have in my component.