# react-select - how do I change the background colour of the control when option x is selected?

Tags: react-select

I'm trying to change the background colour of the control depending on the value of the option that is currently selected

For example, when the value 'new' is selected, I would like to have the control background colour to be red. When it is 'in-progress', I would like the control background colour to be yellow. When it is 'signed' I would like it to be green etc. I should also mention that I have multiple rows in a table with selects in them ('in-progress etc.) and they all have different values depending on the value in each select

I've tried a number of things, but the background colour doesn't change from how it's initially set. I have seen this [How to change react-select options styles when select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60798714/how-to-change-react-select-options-styles-when-select) but this issue resolves when something isSelected and it's a ternary operator. I need something that will be able to have if statements (if value === 'in-progress' for example) or case statements to assign a different background colour to the control based on the value selected in the select component

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Any help would be greatly appreciated